# What does the KEY meaning in the DDL of MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Hello everyone I'm slightly confused by this DDL that has KEY `ID_SECOND` in Mysql db, what does it means? Is it foreign key or something, because I'm usually using Postgresql, and i somewhat confused like what does it equals to in postgresql though. Like if this is My DDL in Mysql:

```
CREATE TABLE `master (
  `ID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ID_SECOND` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
  KEY `ID_SECOND` (`ID_SECOND`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=36 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

And in postgresql currently this is my DDL, i don't know yet how to write that KEY ID_SECOND in the postgresql.

```
CREATE TABLE master (
  ID integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('mst_master_id_seq'::regclass),
  ID_SECOND integer DEFAULT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT master PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Still confused about the ID_SECOND key.
Anyone knows??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

KEY is a [synonym](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table.html) for INDEX, an index that is created without the usage of CREATE INDEX

Comment: Ah Okay, that cleared the 'mystery' for me, Thankyou so much :)